# Can Visual Studio Code show member structure?

Tags: visual-studio-code, pycharm, editor

In pycharm, if your cursor locates at some member function of some class,the status bar will show such structure: `YourClass > some_member_function`, which is very convenient for debugging.Can VSC do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you are looking for here, but when I edit a file with a class and various functions right underneath the tab-bar I can see membership of functions. Hope this helps.